# Can be tomcat and jetty in one java project?

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty

I have in one java project tomcat from Spring Boot and Jetty Client Server from Google. When I turn on one of them for example Tomcat I get something like:

`Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext`

I understand that it is like version issue, but have no idea how to solve it. It's my gradle file:

[image]